# Rest Web Service utilizando Slim Framework, em PHP, dá sempre erro quando chamado por um método Ajax, embora seja executado?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-service, slim

Implementei um WS Rest em PHP, mas quando tento consumir o WS com recurso a um método Ajax ele retorna-me sempre a função de erro. Contudo o WS é gravado e os dados inclusive são gravados na BD. Alguém já lhe aconteceu o mesmo?

Código do WS em PHP (Este é um WS Simples que apenas grava os dados de entrada num ficheiro txt):

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app=new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/gravar_documento', 'gravar_doc');


function gravar_doc(){
    $request=Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data=$request->getbody();
    $dados=json_decode($data,true);
    $dados=(array)$dados[0];
    file_put_contents('test.txt',  $dados["teste"]);


    $app=Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $response->status(200);
    $response->body(json_encode((object)array('success'=>true)));

    }

$app->run();
```

Método Ajax implementado:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://Endereço_foi_ocultado->questões de segurança, mas está bem (pois já executei este WS recorrendo ao SoapUI e não houveram problemas)",
        data: teste_enc,
        success: function(response, b, c){
            alert("Entrou");
        },
        error: function(response,b,c){
            alert("ERRO: "+response.status);

            }
    });
```

Mais uma vez relembro que tudo é executado e os valores são gravados no ficheiro txt, só que a aplicação retorna-me o alert de erro da função de erro do Ajax.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Vá nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador, na seção sobre rede, veja qual é a resposta da requisição ajax. Lá deve haver o motivo de execução esta dando erro. Se os dados são gravados corretamente, o problema está na hora de gerar a resposta.